# How to write while loops inside Logstash Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Is there any way to write loops inside output of Logstash

For a certain message

```
"total:100 name:product 1"
```

I can parse `total` from this message and want to send 100 times to elasticsearch
My code is just pseudocode, is there any way to implement this?

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{total:total} (?m)%{name:name}" }
  }
}
output {
    while count<=time do
      elasticsearch { 
          hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
          index => "data-test"
          user => "elastic"
          password => "changeme"
      }
    end
}
```

Comment: There is not, logstash does not support this.

Comment: one very hacky to do it would be to use the ruby filter to copy the message a hundred time then write this to a file, then use another logstash instance to read the file

Answer (score 1):

My solution is using ruby filter and split event

```
ruby {
    code => '
            arrayOfEvents = Array.new()
            $i = 0
            $num = 10

            while $i < $num  do
                arrayOfEvents.push({ 
                    "key" => $i, 
                    "value" => "value #$i"
                })
                
                puts arrayOfEvents

                event.set("event",arrayOfEvents)
                puts("Inside the loop i = #$i" )
                $i +=1
            end
    '
  }
split {
        field => 'event'
  }
```